# How to make mynavbar have 100% width and the scrollbar to start under it?

Tags: css

I am having basically the same code as here

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_menu

The menu is fixed but the scrollbar is starting from the right of the navbar

I need the scrollbar to start under the menu for example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iq9p.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the example supplied on w3schools, the height of the entire body is made to be greater than the screen height so the scroll bar is applied to the body element. To make a site where the scroll bar is applied to a different element then you'd need to apply the overflow-y css rule to it. Something like this:

Edited: Made it like the w3schools example but with a scroll bar on the main div element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
  <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
  <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you could please add example with my code ? Why you have 90 vh ?

Comment: I've edited it to make it full screen height.

Comment: On the w3schools example replace the .main css rules with this .main {
  position:fixed;
  top:48px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  padding: 16px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

Comment: Okay. I've edited it to make it like the w3schools example.

Answer (score 0):

Both `.navbar` and `.main` need to be set to `position: fixed;`. Then you can use `inset: 55px 0px 0px;` to allow the positioning of `.main` to start just below `.navbar`.

`55px` = rendered height of `.navbar`.

**Note:** it's important that `.main` doesn't have a static height associated with it. Let it be dynamic and grow with the content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  position: fixed; /* required */
  inset: 55px 0px 0px; /* 55px = height of navbar */
  padding: 0 16px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
    <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
    <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```